# How to read string field with digits only from android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentresolver

I have to read contacts from device which are having valid phone numbers. For that right now I'm using following query.

```
        final Uri contentUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        final String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '" + ("1") + "' AND  LENGTH(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + ") >= 10";
        final String[] projection = null;
        final String[] selectionArgs = null;
        final String sortOrder = "upper(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID + ") ASC";
        Cursor phones = mContentResolver.query(contentUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

As you can see in `selection` , im querying for entries with `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = 1` and length of phone number >= 10 , to avoid maximum junk contacts while retrieving from  itself. It works fine , but the problem is , the saved phone numbers might have special characters like `- , ( , )`or a space etc. 
Like +9191-91-22-22-55 , +9191-91-(22 22-55) . I need to get this string without non-digits and without country code (last 10 numbers).

For example : +9190-91-22-22-55  as  9091222255

is there any way to retrieve a string field as formatted like this in SQLite? Or is there any effective way to fulfill my requirement? Thanks in advance..

Comment: a simple `String::replaceAll`, which takes a regex: `value.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");` should do.

Comment: Can it be used in query itself? `value.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");` is in java code right? so that I need to iterate each record again and do this?

Comment: yes, do that when you read the values

Comment: you are telling use this in java or sqlite query?

Comment: can you pls show me a sample query with replace?

Comment: Your assumptions about phone numbers (everything before the last 10 digits is the country code) is wrong almost everywhere.

Comment: May be , but in my requirement I just need the last 10 digits , it could be valid phone number or not , but I am just using this 10 digit number as some ID .